# Authenticate http request coming from an android app

Tags: android, restful-authentication, http-authentication, http-request

i'm building an android app that connect with a server. I do the sign in/authenticate user using their g+ account. Now what I need is how to authenticate the HTTP requests coming from the android app. Thanks

Comment: Post what you have already tried

Comment: I used the getauthtoken method which is offered through the g+ api for android